# Perl: PDF::Table cant find CoreFonts

Tags: perl, pdf-generation

I have a small routine that produces a pdf from some tabular data.  It works but output isn't pretty so I am trying to use PDF::Table.

I load all the data into a 2D table of strings and then call table:

```
    # Create a new PDF                                                                                                                                                           
    my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
    my $pdf = PDF::API2::Simple->new( file => $io );

    $pdf->add_font('VerdanaBold');
    $pdf->add_font('Verdana');

    # Add a page                                                                                                                                                                 
    $pdf->add_page();

    my @table_data;

    # < snipped code to build table_data>

    $pdftable->table(
        # required params                                                                                                                                                        
        $pdf,
        $pdf->current_page,
        \@table_data,
        -x  =>  $pdf->margin_left,                                                                                                                     
        -start_y => 500,
        -next_y => 700,
        -start_h => 300,
        -next_h => 500,
        # some optional params                                                                                                                                                   
        -w => 570,
        -padding => 5,
        -padding_right => 10,
        -background_color_odd => "gray",
        -background_color_even => "lightblue", #cell background color for even rows                                                                                              
        );
```

This code is copied from the CPAN Doc for PDF::Table.

I get an error:

"Can't locate object method \"corefont\" via package \"PDF::API2::Simple\" at /usr/local/share/perl5/PDF/Table.pm line 256.\n"

Any hints?

Comment: What distribution?  Which version of perl?

Comment: PDF-Table-0.9.6_h3, SSIMMS/PDF-API2-2.020, This is perl, v5.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to work around this one even if I did not manage to find the root cause.

the workaround is to define a font before you call Table:

`my $font =      $pdf->add_font('Verdana');`

and then pass `$font` into Table as a parameter so Table does not go looking for fonts.

```
    $pdftable->table(
        # required params                                                                                                                                                    
        $pdf,
        $pdf->current_page,
        \@table_data,
       -font => $font,
       ....
```

I spent some time hunting through the code of PDF::API2 and failed to find a difinition of corefont even though it it reference all over the place???